# [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so' : file not found

Tags: php, ubuntu, vertica, unixodbc

Right now I am trying to connect with vertica using PHP on Ubuntu. And I am getting this error

PHP 7.2.7
Ubuntu 18.04

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so' : file not found
```

I already have that file in that route with all permissions.

This is my /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[Vertica]
Description = Vertica driver
Driver   = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so
Driver64 = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so
```

This is my /etc/vertica.ini

```
[Driver]
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
ODBCInstLib = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/vertica/lib64
LogLevel=4
LogPath=/tmp
```

I got the libverticaodbc.so file from vertica-client-fips-9.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Can you test ODBC connectivity by adding a `Vertica` entry in `/etc/odbc.ini` and running `echo 'select * from nodes;' | isql Vertica`?

Comment: Try `ldd /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so` and look for not found messages